# Показательная програмка

Tags: любой-язык

Посоветуйте не сложную програмку(или задачку) со смыслом, которая будет демонстрировать все(или большинство) операции в программировании (условия, циклы, множественный выбор и т.д.)

Comment: Я бы тоже посмотрел, однако)

Comment: Язва ты, однако. =)

Comment: Я, кстати, без иронии. Просто посмотреть на минимальный осмысленный код, в к-ром хотя бы большинство операций (от if-else через битовые операторы, сравнение строк и процедуры к интерфейсам/классам) было бы интересно) Задачка даже вполне осуществима, но мне было бы лень)

Comment: «В программировании» — нереально, код, если чудом и возможен, то будет круче дитя Франкенштейна, так что о смысле говорить будет сложно. В пределах одной парадигмы — возможно и осуществимо. Я не уверен, но посмотрел бы на различные реализации интерпретаторов/виртуальных машин.

Comment: Ловлю на слове. Из вредности на выхах напишу, чтоб все прочел.
PHP, ес-но

Comment: Да, такое есть. Называется документация. Еще можно книгу купить, там то же много всего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В любой сколь-нибудь сложной программе будут все перечисленные Вами операции. Например, множественный выбор (конструкция `switch`) удобна для анализа ввода пользователя (меню) или для создания конечного автомата для разбора строки (идем по строке, смотрим каждый следующий символ, в зависимости от этого символа переводим программу в какое-либо определенное состояние). Циклы - встречаются практически везде. В особенности, когда речь идет о работе с массивами однотипных данных. На функции (и процедуры, если есть различие) достаточно большую программу так же практически всегда можно разбить. Следует подходить к вопросу логически: выделять повторяющиеся операции в функции или обрамлять как ф-ции законченные блоки программы для повышения читаемости кода. Я считаю, что нужен творческий подход. В качестве интересной цели возьмите, например, создание игры. Можно сделать свою реализацию тетриса. Еще вариант - берете произвольный учебник с примерами программ и смотрите в конец :-)

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе [архив задач](http://acm.timus.ru/problemset.aspx?space=1&page=all), со встроенным компилятором. Отправляешь им код свой, они проверяют и сразу говорят правильно, что неправильно. Там около 1000 задач, и все очень хорошие, выбирай, какие душе угодно. П.С. я бы посоветовал задачу номер [1493](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1493).